# Python operator module equivalent in Java for basic method references

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

As of Java 8, method references exist. I have a simple interface which I would like to use existing (preferably in a `java.something` package) method references to implement.

```java
public class Calculator {
    private interface BinaryFunction<A, B, R> {
        R apply(A a, B b);
    }

    private <A, B, R> R apply(BinaryFunction<A, B, R> binaryFunction, A a, B b) {
        return binaryFunction.apply(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        calculator.apply((a, b) -> a + b, 1, 2);            // 3
        calculator.apply(Math::addExact, 1, 2);             // 3
        calculator.apply((a, b) -> a || b, true, false);    // true
//        calculator.apply(?::?, true, false);              // true
    }
}
```

*`Math::addExact` isn't the same as `+`, but it's close enough for me--I actually prefer getting `ArithmeticException("integer overflow")` thrown for my purposes.*

If this were Python, I'd use the [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module, but I don't know if there is such a thing in Java.

So is there any static method in a `java.something` package that can go in the `?::?` part which is equivalent to the `||` operator?

Comment: Are you asking for a method that does `||` on a pair of inputs?

Comment: @dimo414 Yeah. And it ought to be in a built-in package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [`java.lang.Boolean.logicalOr(boolean, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#logicalOr-boolean-boolean-) method for this purpose.

So in your case you would use:

```
calculator.apply(Boolean::logicalOr, true, false);
```